# How to convert all datatypes as String while creating an avsc file through avro-tools.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, avro

I am generating an avsc schema files while loading it into HDFS .

The file is getting created as below:-

```
 "fields" : [ 
    {     "name" : "AGGREGATE",     
          "type" : [ "null", "string" ],     
          "default" : null,    
          "columnName" : "AGGREGATE",     
          "sqlType" : "1"   
    }, 
    {     "name" : "LSTIME",     
          "type" : [ "null", "long" ],     
          "default" : null,     
          "columnName" : "LSTIME",    
          "sqlType" : "93"   
    },
```

However as per my requirement i need all the datatypes to be converted to string datatype while creating a hive table .

I have tried the solution `java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar compile -string schema`  but it is not working.

Please can anyone help.